Simplifying script syntax for a course
I am planning to teach Python to a bunch of beginers in Blender.
To make the syntax look more inviting to a beginer's eye, I use simple functions like :
    def objectNamed(nom):
        return bpy.data.objects[nom]  

So that I can simply code:
    myObject = objectNamed("cube") 

The problem is that I have to add these function definitions at the beginning of my script. It's ugly.
I am looking for a solution to avoid that, and hide this code somewhere else.
I will be able to send the kids a file, like a startup file if needed, but asking them to install a Python library is probably the best way to make them feel lost.
I may have to update this hidden library of mine quite often.

That sounds like a general python question rather than a Blender-specific one!

Imagine that you were teaching someone English, but in order to make it "easier", you would invent your own, "simpler" words. Would you really teach English then? You're adding an unnecessary layer of abstraction.

Bit nit picky but if you're teaching a Python course then it makes sense to adhere to Python syntax convention, specifically, reserving CapCase for class names and snake_case for basically everything else. Relevant section of the Python style guide

Sorry for puting the post at the wrong place.
I need a technical advice here. Thank you for adding some pedagogical considerations, but, I must admit that adding pedagogical consideration without having much knowledge of the context ... somehow ruins your credibility in pedagogical matters ...

Maybe my title is not clear but, i don'y want to change Python's syntax but to hide the long Bpy instructions like bpy.data.objects["theCube"]

Kinda agree with the comments. Not really a Blender specific question (but hey, why not) and arguably not necessarily the best "bet" for simplification in a teaching environment. Yet making a "simpler bpy layer" is not unheard of, see EasyBPY. Though it's not really focused on teaching but making the bpy interface overall more friendly to people unfamiliar with Blender data structure afaik.
If you do want to do such a layer, you could rake example from easyBPY. And some things in your example reveal themselves as quite confusing and avoided by easyBPY:

using one language (here you seem to use english and french?) I would totally understand making a non-english layer, but mixing multiple languages would make things needlessly complicated, requiring people to switch gear every odd word reduces learning efficiency.

functions use short phrase-like names with underscores. Wording a name query as "objectNamed" isn't the smoothest thing. Get_object_name is already way simpler.


I think if you want to do such a layer, you need to set yourself a clear target public and a set of rules to better serve them.
On the technical side, if I had to do such a thing, I would make it as a module. Just like easyBPY.
Basically a python file where you put all your functions in. And in any other file you need these functions, you can use from my_module import function_name (or import * to import all functions at once).
To learn more:

6. Modules — Python 3.12.6 documentation
Introducing: EasyBPY! (Easy Python for Blender) - YouTube


Thanks, If fact, it won't be multi lingual ! ( I just made an example for this post and forgot to translate a French word ... ). It will be 100% French.

EasyBPY seems to answer my question ... except for the linguistic aspect ...
Which is still negociable ...  Thank you Lauloque !

Note if you can share a startup file you can embed your script in a text data block using the text editor and enable Text > Register, this will automatically run the script when the file is opened. You do have to enable execution of scripts in the preferences or accept the popup on file startup. This might be easier than using pip for kids.

@Gorgious, that's great. But wait ... if I define a function in this registered piece of code, it won't be usable in the other code I will use for teaching purpose ?

@Gorgious, I think that there is a way to call the contained in another text file ...
How ... If anybody knows ...

https://blenderartists.org/t/b3-2-multiple-text-script/1446043/7

This seems to work BUT youy need to import all functions with a :   Myfunc = TEXT1.Myfunc   ... which is annoying ...

Hence, just use modules ;)

I think you can register you functions to globals so they are available in the global namespace. not sure though

A good way to do this is to use modules.
Text, named simplfyingBpy, where definitions are made :
import bpy
def getName(name):
    return bpy.data.objects[name]  

Second text where I use them :
import bpy
import sys
sys.modules["simplfyingBpy"] = bpy.data.texts['simplfyingBpy'].as_module()
from simplfyingBpy import *

myCube = getName( "cube" )
print( myCube.location )

This is a perfect solution for my problem.
As you can guess, I noob like me couldn't get it just by himself :
Thanks @Gorgious and :
How to import text data blocks as modules using the 'from/import' statement?
